# calendar in php

Tags: php, javascript

How can I make a calendar in php so that the users will not have to input the date manually.

Comment: Are you referring to a datepicker, such as those implemented by jQuery, YUI, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more a javascript feature, actually.

There are many javascript library to do this. One of it is [jQuery UI DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/). I highly recommended this one.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using the js calendar from http://www.dynarch.com/ and it's nice and it has many options like limiting the date selection within a period, multiple date selection etc.,